# How can I run Mojave on an iMac that won’t run Mojave?

Tags: high-sierra, imac, mojave

Last week a relative gave me his old iMac 27” 2011 [HDD]. I Planned to run it off a bootable external SSD with Mojave 10.14.6 installed — I wasn’t aware of the hardware limitations i.e. the iMac’s hardware only supports MacOS up to High Sierra.

How could I run Mojave on this iMac?

Responders may suggest 1) patch with dosdude's patcher (not compatible with this model iMac) or 2) use High Sierra. My problem with the 2nd suggestion is that I'm already set on Mojave with software licenses (with machine install limits/hardware locks etc.) and all sorts of custom software patching setup for audio production that will be a nightmare to replicate (obviously I can't use a Mojave Time Machine BU to go backwards).

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: In what sense are Mojave and High Sierra incompatible for you?

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is here. Are you looking for ways to get Mojave to run on an iMac 2011? Are you wondering what use a iMac running High Sierra could be to you? Are you looking for differences between High Sierra and Mojave which would make use of both in parallel difficult/impossible? Please be specific in your question (and keep in mind that some of them are probably too much a matter of individual taste and opinion to really be answerable).

Comment: @lhf They (Mojave / High Sierra) in themselves aren’t incompatible. One of the computers is incapable of running Mojave and my operational installations I use are Mojave. That is the incompatibility I refer to. Also I can’t rollback a fully operational Mojave install to High Sierra without pulling teeth.

Comment: @nohillside yes, I’m looking for ways to get Mojave to run on a machine that will not run Mojave.

Comment: I've edited the question to focus in this.

Comment: Having said that: running two Macs with different macOS versions isn't a problem as such, as long as the applications are the same (or at least use the same data format).

Comment: Actually, http://osxdaily.com/2018/09/27/run-macos-mojave-unsupported-mac-dosdude-patch/ is the first link coming up when I search "running mojave on old hardware"

Comment: Yes, my original question was edited and it included information that was referring to the dosdude patch. But my machine is one of the few that has a GPU incompatibility.

Comment: I would mention about GPU and Wifi incompatibility.

Comment: @Vaultnaemsae My strong recommendation would be to use this iMac with a compatible macOS version. Besides the obvious hassle of trying to get it to work with an unsupported OS, this model iMac is renowned for having problems develop over time with its GPU (these can be rectified, but it's a bit involved and not for most users). My point being that if it works at present, then put it to use for a different purpose (i.e. if your software doesn't run on it). Otherwise use it with the software you need on High Sierra. Most software that runs on macOS Mojave will run on macOS High Sierra just fine.

Comment: As much as I’d like to rebuild a relationship with old mate High Sierra I don’t much fancy the idea of de-authorising all software licences in Mojave and re-authorising them in High Sierra. Seems like a lot of faffing about. I guess there’s not much other choice though.

Comment: It‘s still not clear what your concern about having two different versions of macOS on different machines is. They aren‘t that different, you won’t notice much during daily use.

Comment: @nohillside if the original question hadn’t been edited it might be clearer. The edit removed key information. It has become clear there is no practicable solution that will enable Mojave on this system. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry if the edit was too aggressive. You can always edit things back in yourself if essentials got lost.

Comment: What software are you using that requires de-authorising and re-authorising with a change of OS?

Comment: @benwiggy you may have missed the point. If I were upgrading OS it wouldn’t likely be an issue - no need to deauthorize. Rolling back is another story since I have to create a ‘new’ Mac device.

Comment: @Vaultnaemsae I've rolled back the OS before and not had to do this with a variety of software that needs authorisation. Mind you, this was restoring a backup from TM. If you're wiping and reinstalling, then that might be different.

Comment: @benwiggy Gotcha. No Time Machine backup available here since I’ve been on Mojave for quite a while. Didn’t foresee any need to rewind prior to now.

Comment: Hang on: You've never installed the software on this computer, so it will surely need a new authorisation anyway? Software running from an SSD set up for another machine won't be valid.

Comment: @benwiggy I’m not 100% sure how it works but I am running both Mojave installations on the MacBook Pro with no issue — would it be the same if I tried to run the ext. SSD on another Mojave compatible device? There’s not a lot of clear info on this. Licensing methods are all different and beyond the scope of this discussion. Last week I upgraded the external SSD to Catalina but rolled it back with a Mojave Time Machine BU. I didn’t have any licence issues bar one which was a relatively easy fix. So, I know I could rollback if I had a High Sierra Time Machine BU.

Comment: No. Different hardware requires different seat licence and authorisation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try http://dosdude1.com/mojave/, although I don't know if that would work in your configuration.